# Connecting DB using `HTML5` is possible?

Tags: asp.net, html

Is it possible to connect to a  `DATABASE` which is in `WEBSERVER` through `HTML5` only without using `ASP.NET`, `JSP` etc.

Comment: You're looking for a database with a HTTP API, [such as the REST API in CouchDB](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API). So instead of ASP.NET or JSP you'd need a specific database which doesn't need an "active server pages" front-end.

Comment: please give comment befor giving down vote, i am new to webdevelopment?

Comment: you mean without any server-side code or <script></script>?

Comment: This is not a forum; __this is a questions and answer site, and I'm afraid your post isn't really a question, because [real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).__ [Please read the FAQ for more information.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html5 is a browser display language. It has no inherent methods or capabilities to connect to server side technology. You will always need a server side technology to connect to a database, even when using AJAX through a service. When you think about it, isn't this how you should want it? Would you really WANT to have a client connect directly to your database for any reason? You'd be exposing authentication information and allowing direct public access to your data store. Not terribly sensible.

Comment: Get with the program brother! RESTful JSON no-SQL document databases are all the rage! :)

Comment: @bzlm: Maybe, but you still wouldn't want to expose direct db access publicly without some measure of protection. A RESTful service is still a server-side layer between client and db. OP is looking to go from client to db direct through html5 (from the way I read it).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No".

The slightly longer answer is "Maybe, it depends". e.g. If your database is CouchDB, then it is possible to host [HTML documents directly](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/standalone.html) on it (as an attachment to a regular CouchDB document). These can include JavaScript which can hold your application logic.

Comment: Thanks for giving me proper way... Now is it right??? Pleas..tell me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specification called Web Sql Html 5, which is a variant of SQL. Unfortunately, this specification is stopped. You can see more details on these links.

[Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)

[HTML 5 Web SQL Database](http://openbit.co.uk/?p=135)

[Introducing Web SQL Database](http://html5doctor.com/introducing-web-sql-databases/)